Decide when both Ajax call and fetch has finished
I am developing something that will run a test. One part of the test is done by going to php via ajax and back again to get some things from the server. The other is to fetch things from an external api.
Both things takes around 3-5 seconds each to run depending on some parameters.
I need to know when both cases has finished so I know that the complete test has finished, not just parts of them.
I have tried below but it puts the flag to completed when the Ajax request is done but not the performance test:
function runAutomaticTest() {
    if (isRunningTest) {
      return;
    }  
    isRunningTest = true;
  
    // Run performance test
    var performanceTestPromise = runPerformanceTest(urlToTest);
  
    // Make AJAX call
    var ajaxCallPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajax_site_url,
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
          action: "automatic-test",
        },
        success: function (response) {
          
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
          
        },
      });
    });
  
    // Wait for both tasks to complete
    Promise.all([performanceTestPromise, ajaxCallPromise])
      .then(() => {
        isRunningTest = false;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        isRunningTest = false;
      });
  }

Basic structure of runPerformanceTest:
function runPerformanceTest(url) {
  fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => {
      const test = json.test?.metrics;
      if (test) {
        showcontent()
      }

      const test2 = json.test2;
      if (test2) {
        showcontent2()
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
    });
}

How can I run both tests at the same time (which it does now) and know when both of them has finished?

I made some changes to the code style (for readability), other than that everything is pretty much exactly what you have except I added a return statement to the runPerformanceTest function. In addition, I added resolve(response) in the success callback and reject(error) in the error callback of the Ajax function.
const runAjaxTest = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: ajax_site_url,
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        action: "automatic-test",
      },
      success: function (response) {
          resolve(response);
      },
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
          reject(error);
      },
    });
  });
};

const runPerformanceTest = (url) => {
  return fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => {
      const test = json.test?.metrics;
      if (test) {
        showcontent();
      }

      const test2 = json.test2;
      if (test2) {
        showcontent2();
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
    });
};

const runAutomaticTest = () => {
  if (isRunningTest) {
    return;
  }

  isRunningTest = true;

  // Wait for both tasks to complete
  Promise.all([runPerformanceTest(urlToTest), runAjaxTest()])
    .then(() => {
      isRunningTest = false;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      isRunningTest = false;
    });
};


Hmm it doesn't seem to even go into the .then() of the Promise.all. I console log to see that Ajax is finished in its success part, and I console log to see that showcontent2() is running in runPerformanceTest. But the isRunningTest=false is never firing, I tried to console log in both the then() and error() of the Promise.all

I want to suggest you run each test separately to ascertain whether both methods run to completion without errors. In addition, you should set up a debugger, adding break points to parts of the code to trace the calls.

I fixed it, I had to add "resolve(response);" in the success function in Ajax to make it resolve. Please update with this and I can accept the answer.

@eligolf I have updated the answer to include the omitted resolve(response)

runPerformanceTest() is not returning a promise, it isn't returning anything. So performanceTestPromise is getting set to undefined.
You just need to put a return in front of your fetch statement.
function runPerformanceTest(url) {
  return fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => {
      const test = json.test?.metrics;
      if (test) {
        showcontent()
      }

      const test2 = json.test2;
      if (test2) {
        showcontent2()
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
    });
}

